# How to solve the conflicts between the maps click event and clicking the markers to show popups in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I created a click event on the map using the following code.

```js
mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

And also a marker with popup.

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([loc.lon,loc.lat]);
marker.setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnMove:true}).setText(`Hello`));
marker.addTo(mymap);
```

When I click the marker, both events are fired.

What I expected to happen is only the event of marker (show the popup) is fired. But the function `onMapClick` is also fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case I had the event bind to my layer but it should be the same. Here is what I did to prevent conflict between map click and marker click in order to show popup properly.

```
map.on('click', 'myLayerId', (e) => {
 if (e.originalEvent.target.classList.contains('mapboxgl-marker')) return;

 doSomething...
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Even though the same code didn't work because the click target of the marker is a path without class. But I solve the problem with similar way

Answer (score 0):

When a map 'click' event is triggered, you can check if the original element that was clicked was a marker and if so, return the function early - thereby not performing the map click actions.

```
map.on('click', (e) => {
    if (e.originalEvent.target.closest('.mapboxgl-marker')) {
        return // Click target was a marker so do nothing…
    }

    // Do something...
}
```

mokokom's solution is nearly there, but with the markers being inline svgs, the elements which are clicked tend to be internal svg elements like `<path>` or `<circle>`. These elements don't have the `.mapboxgl-marker` class so you need to look up the tree to find it with `.closest`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more niche circumstance, however I was finding a conflict with `map.on('click',Layername,(e)=>{});`

Using Nextjs 13 and mapbox-gl, while building the map on a client component, you may encounter the same conflict.

To remedy this, I added my on('click') components to the end of the on('load') function. I didn't call any specified layer, but instead made a separate array with my layer names.

Additionally, I used `map.queryRenderedFeatures()` instead of designating the specific layer to work on.

```js
  for(var x in clickLayer)
  {
    if(clickLayer[x].includes("Layer")){ continue;} // Resolved conflict with running 2x per pageload
     clickLayer[x]+="Layer";
     try{console.log(map.getLayer(clickLayer[x]))}
     catch(e){console.error(e)}
   }

     let ActivePopup;
     map.on('click',(e)=>{
        const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point,{layers:clickLayer});
        
        if(features.length<0)
        {
           console.log("Click binding failed.");
           return;
        }
        const feature = features[0];
        console.log("Clicked: ",feature.properties.title);

})
```